# Block only directories using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My directory tree:

```
/assets
  /css
      style.css
  /js
      script.js
```

I want to block all direcotries when I open url for example: http://example.com/assets, but I will must open http://example.com/assets/css/style.css

How can I solve this problem using .htaccess on apache server?

Comment: What do you mean by block exactly? Return a certain HTTP status, prevent an index of the folder from displaying?

Comment: I don't want to see people my asset folder's files like a tree. If user will open only http://example.com/assets, he/she must see 404 error or 503 forbidden...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
```

This will prevent directory browsing and return a 403 Forbidden status when browsing directly to directories.

Comment: Thank's for solving problem!